# Converting curl request to Golang

Tags: go, curl

So this curl request to the paypal payouts API works:

```
curl --silent -v 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "${client_id}:${client_secret}" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

one thing I am confused about:  the `-d` option is for data in the body of the HTTP request - does the -d option make it a POST request or is the curl request above a GET request with a body? I would guess that latter but I am unsure given the output of `curl --help`.

In golang I have:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const (
    PayPalTestClientID = "Aeit5RskDRN8eUUMB0Ud3RjA_z6feWMUHktwlJZMeQMo9A9ulbKK"
    PayPalTestSecret   = "EAAqyzrOTUWf-OFJCB4BxgXT4xuravL7pnkC8Tn20HYtZExd1mFO"
)

func main() {

    //reader := bytes.NewBuffer()
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en_US")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Basic %s:%s", PayPalTestClientID, PayPalTestSecret))

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var v interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &v);

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Print(v)
}
```

the client/secret were obfuscated, so they won't work as written above. But using the real creds I get:

> 2020/01/31 16:05:07 map[error:invalid_client error_description:Client
>   Authentication failed]

The real creds do work with the curl command tho.

Comment: Read the curl man pages for the `-d` flag.

Comment: Open postman, import request from curl, check out the code snippets (go is also there)

Comment: the curl -v flag shows that the curl request was a POST request, which is absurd given that the -X POST option was not used.

Comment: Is not absurd. Using `-d` you are going to send a POST request

Comment: It is absurd, since in a GET request you can include a body if you want. Why `-d` forces a POST request without using `-X POST` is beyond me.

Comment: Not so absurd. Check here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.3

Comment: its absurd because a GET request can have a body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The credentials provided are valid? Cause i receive a sonorus 401, `Authentication Failed`.

***NOTE***: Using the `-d` in `cURL`, you are going to send a `POST` request instead of a `GET`. Due to this behaviour, your proably want to send a `POST` request instead of a `GET`

You can use my little http library: https://github.com/alessiosavi/Requests/

```golang
package main

import requests "github.com/alessiosavi/Requests"

func main() {
    req, err := requests.InitRequest("https://postman-echo.com/basic-auth", "GET", []byte{}, false, false)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR! ", err)
    }
    req.CreateHeaderList("Accept", "application/json", "Accept-Language", "en_US", "Authorization", "postman:password")
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp := req.ExecuteRequest(client)
    fmt.Println(resp.Dump())
}
```

You can change the data (URL, post data, headers) with the one that you need for authenticate to the service.

In your case, will be something like this:

```golang
package main

import requests "github.com/alessiosavi/Requests"

const (
    ID= "Aeit5RskDRN8eUUMB0Ud3RjA_z6feWMUHktwlJZMeQMo9A9ulbKK"
    SECRET= "EAAqyzrOTUWf-OFJCB4BxgXT4xuravL7pnkC8Tn20HYtZExd1mFO"
)

func main() {
    req, err := requests.InitRequest("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", "GET", []byte{"grant_type=client_credentials"}, false, false)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR! ", err)
    }
    req.CreateHeaderList("Accept", "application/json", "Accept-Language", "en_US", "Authorization", ID+":"+SECRET)
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp := req.ExecuteRequest(client)
    fmt.Println(resp.Dump())
}
```